# Can I live-debug any website on browser?

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-debugger

I know there are [tools](https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_debugging.asp) which allow us to debug our own website? How can I debug(or analyze) any website, for eg:- Amazon, Google?

Basically, I want to add `print` functions(in JS) and add breakpoints (in JS) in the execution of a website. How is that achievable, if at all.

We can live-debug (and play-around) CSS and HTML on the browser itself, but how to debug JS on the browser?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/

Answer (score 1):

On **Google Chrome** for exemple, open the *DevTools* window by pressing `F12` and right-click on the  HTML element. Then go on `Break on ->` and choose `subtree modifications`. Your app will stop at page loading and you will be able to do step by step analysis.